# how can I find an error in spring boot debug?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to use thymeleaf to pass an object to a spring controller but I have an error that I don't konow how to resolve it. The error is

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

and in the console I can't find any error or warning.
I extend the debug of spring boot putting this two options in application.properties:

```
logging.level.web=debug
logging.level.root=debug
```

but I can't find an error that helps me, please I need some help to find a solution
can I extend more the debug of spring?

This is the popover when I try to load the object with thymeleaf:

```
<div th:fragment="search_exams">
    <div id="popover-search-exams" style="display: none;">
        <form th:action="@{/exams/search}" th:object="${exam}" method="get" id="form-search">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="examDate">Fecha</label>
                <input class="container-fluid" type="date" th:field="*{examDate}" name="examDate" id="search_date"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="examHour">Hora</label>
                <input class="container-fluid" type="time" th:field="*{examHour}" name="examHour" id="search_hour"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="searchSubject">Asignatura</label>
                <input class="container-fluid" type="text" name ="searchSubject" id="search_subject"/>
                <span id="search_message" style="display:none;"></span> 
                <input class="container-fluid" type="hidden" th:field="*{subjectId}" name="subjectId" id="search_subjectId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                        
                <label for="lesson">Temas</label>
                <input class="container-fluid" type="text" th:field="*{lesson}" name="lesson" id="search_lesson"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="form-new-mark">                     
                <label for="mark">Nota</label>
                <input class="container-fluid" type="text" th:field="*{mark}" name="mark" step="0.01" id="search_mark" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                        
                <label for="notes">Observaciones</label>
                <textarea class="container-fluid" type="text" th:field="*{notes}" name="notes" id="search_notes"></textarea>
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-search-exams" value="submit" disabled>Buscar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is the controller

```
@Log4j2 
@Controller

public class ExamController {
@Autowired
private ExamRestController examRestController;  

@Autowired
private SubjectRestController subjectRestController;

public SubjectRestController getSubjectRestController() {
    return subjectRestController;
}

public ExamRestController getExamRestController() {
    return examRestController;
}

private final int NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE_IN_SEARCH = 25;

@GetMapping("/exams/search")
public String examSearch(@RequestBody Exam exam, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page, Model model) {
    try {
        Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(page, NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE_IN_SEARCH);

        Page<Exam> pageExam = getExamRestController().getSearchExams(exam, pageableRequest);            

        model.addAttribute("exams", pageExam);
        model.addAttribute("subjects", getSubjectRestController().getSubjects());
        model.addAttribute("count", pageExam.getTotalElements());
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        model.addAttribute("element", NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE_IN_SEARCH+page*NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE_IN_SEARCH);
        model.addAttribute("elementsPerPage", NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE_IN_SEARCH);

        log.info("loaded exams in a /exams/search");

        return "search_exams";
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("error loading exams in /exams/search");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }       
}
```

And this is the debug of console

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/exams
Cookie: JSESSIONID=EE7C7DF57B279D49A5248D9A7649ECC6; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBbGJhIEJsYW5jbyIsInJvbGVzIjpbeyJpZCI6eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1Nzk4MDk2MDksIm1hY2hpbmVJZGVudGlmaWVyIjoxNDI2MzY5NCwicHJvY2Vzc0lkZW50aWZpZXIiOjE4ODM2LCJjb3VudGVyIjoxNDA1MjA1MCwiZGF0ZSI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOTAwMCwidGltZSI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOTAwMCwidGltZVNlY29uZCI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOX0sIm5hbWUiOiJST0xFX1NUVURFTlQifV0sImlhdCI6MTU4NDExOTY1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTg0MTIzMjU1fQ.Wy-zl1CeFNxs4jcpyfQEGg0R3yeu_C8e-KoIn4iuC9A
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.961 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=EE7C7DF57B279D49A5248D9A7649ECC6; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBbGJhIEJsYW5jbyIsInJvbGVzIjpbeyJpZCI6eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1Nzk4MDk2MDksIm1hY2hpbmVJZGVudGlmaWVyIjoxNDI2MzY5NCwicHJvY2Vzc0lkZW50aWZpZXIiOjE4ODM2LCJjb3VudGVyIjoxNDA1MjA1MCwiZGF0ZSI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOTAwMCwidGltZSI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOTAwMCwidGltZVNlY29uZCI6MTU3OTgwOTYwOX0sIm5hbWUiOiJST0xFX1NUVURFTlQifV0sImlhdCI6MTU4NDExOTY1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTg0MTIzMjU1fQ.Wy-zl1CeFNxs4jcpyfQEGg0R3yeu_C8e-KoIn4iuC9A
2020-03-13 18:18:17.963 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is EE7C7DF57B279D49A5248D9A7649ECC6
2020-03-13 18:18:17.964 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /search/%7Bdata%7D
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1a24094d
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.965 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/logout'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /search/{data}' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /search/{data}' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /search/{data}' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestWrapperFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.966 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtTokenFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.971 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "username" : "Alba Blanco" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2020-03-13 18:18:17.972 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "username" : "Alba Blanco" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class org.tutoring.web.models.Users in collection: users
2020-03-13 18:18:17.972 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Sending command {find : BsonString{value='users'}} to database tokensDb on connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:1724}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
2020-03-13 18:18:17.973 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command execution completed
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /search/{data}' doesn't match 'POST /login
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.974 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ddf42f4f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f1887d9: Username: Alba Blanco; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_STUDENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_STUDENT'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.975 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.975 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@17d2b075
2020-03-13 18:18:17.975 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.975 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/search_posts'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/wall/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/resources/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/css/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/js/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/webjars/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/register'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/api/auth/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/search/{data}'; against '/exams/**'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /search/{data}?data=; Attributes: [authenticated]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.976 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ddf42f4f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f1887d9: Username: Alba Blanco; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_STUDENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_STUDENT
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3040768d, returned: 1
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /search/{data}?data= reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/search/%7Bdata%7D]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.977 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /search/{data}
2020-03-13 18:18:17.980 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/search/{data}]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.981 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/search/{data}] are [/**]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.981 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/search/{data}] are {}
2020-03-13 18:18:17.981 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/search/{data}] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@10817f46]]] and 1 interceptor
2020-03-13 18:18:17.981 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/search/%7Bdata%7D] is: -1
2020-03-13 18:18:17.982 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@763a8ad2
2020-03-13 18:18:17.982 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2020-03-13 18:18:17.982 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2020-03-13 18:18:17.983 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-03-13 18:18:17.983 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-03-13 18:18:17.983 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1a24094d
2020-03-13 18:18:17.983 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.985 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestWrapperFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtTokenFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@d2caebe0: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A45269E85E76F8D731914F24A2F2E639; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.986 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.987 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?data= reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-03-13 18:18:17.987 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.987 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2020-03-13 18:18:17.988 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.988 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.988 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2020-03-13 18:18:17.989 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2020-03-13 18:18:17.991 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2020-03-13 18:18:17.992 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2020-03-13 18:18:17.992 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@a99792d] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@a99792d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-03-13 18:18:17.993 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
2020-03-13 18:18:17.994 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5777be98:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@87be136:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61734]], Read from buffer: [0]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.994 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5777be98:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@87be136:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61734]], Read direct from socket: [0]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.994 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5777be98:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@87be136:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61734]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2020-03-13 18:18:18.609 DEBUG 15164 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1584119898609 sessioncount 1
2020-03-13 18:18:18.609 DEBUG 15164 --- [Engine[Tomcat]]] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2020-03-13 18:18:22.110 DEBUG 15164 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Checking status of 127.0.0.1:27017
2020-03-13 18:18:22.111 DEBUG 15164 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=1.1 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
2020-03-13 18:18:22.117 DEBUG 15164 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Checking status of 127.0.0.1:27017
2020-03-13 18:18:22.117 DEBUG 15164 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=1.0 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
2020-03-13 18:18:22.118 DEBUG 15164 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Checking status of localhost:27017
2020-03-13 18:18:22.118 DEBUG 15164 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=1.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

Any help will be appreciated, please if someone has any clue make me know
Thanks

Comment: Issue is spring/thymleaf not able to route request to correct controller method. One thing you can try is changing it to a post request  (on both thymleaf and  spring)as get request should not have data in request body. Also try chrome dev tool > network tab to check route getting hit when form submit

Comment: >2020-03-13 18:18:17.980 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [**/search/{data}**]
2020-03-13 18:18:17.981 DEBUG 15164 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/search/{data}] are [/**]

Comment: ..i doubt it is a bug, rather a mis-configuration (spring-security seems ok/recognizes `/search/data`, but) there's no matching (registered) Handler (= `@RequestMapping`) in your application.

Comment: ...and `/search/data` is mentioned in the logs, while the posted code would imply `/exams/search/`, please check this mismatch, which could also fix your issue.

Comment: I change to post request with the same result. In the network tab I get this result name GET /search/%7Bdata%7D?data= HTTP/1.1 and I don't understand why

Comment: On the other hand I don't have any @RequestMapping for /search/data because the action that I want is /exams/search. If I write this direction in chrome it works perfectly.

Comment: There is no /search/data in all my code, so I don't understand what is the origin
of that, the th:action is /exams/search. I try to find something in google but I am not lucky.